# Couchbase - Can the select key value in N1QL DP4 have a special character?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I'm trying to do a query on some data with the field "@id" but N1QL returns an array of empty JSON objects.

It has accepted "_" in the key but I cannot get a correct responce with the following.

SELECT @id FROM objects;

Is there a way i can escape the @ symbol?

Example entry in 'objects' Bucket:

```
{
    "@id": "082338c7-cf07-48eb-9a8a-942a54434da9",
    "@data": {
        "hello": "World"
    },
    "@type": "t_096c8ebffb4ceb49e97035dffd9cb015-155",
    "_date_created": "2015-01-28T15: 19: 37.928Z",
    "_date_modified": "2015-01-28T17: 06: 40.974Z"
}
```

Result of 'SELECT @id FROM objects;'

```
{
  "results": [
    {},
    {}
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you have objects with an empty id? Can you paste a sample query result?

Comment: I only have a handfull of objects in the bucket and none of them have empty '@id' fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following ( ` ):

```
SELECT `@id` FROM objects;
```

Comment: Perfect, i never even thought of trying the grave accent. Thanks.